# InfoPath validation rules not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-rules

I have customized a nornal SharePoint list with InfoPath that will not allow users to upload any attachments with special characters. However when I click on the Submit button, though the form cannot be submitted, a list entry is being created in the list.

How can I prevent the list from creating items? Is there a way that I can enforce a rule on the Submit button? If so how?

I have followed the following posts:

https://bdequaasteniet.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/validating-attachment-filenames-on-a-sharepoint-infopath-form-2/

Though I'm getting the default pop-up, the data is submitted in the backend list

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always add a formatting rule on a button and disable the button or hide it if the conditions are not met.

Comment: Welll tried that as well....but it doesn't work. I'm assuming it because its the default attachment column